# Bar-cobar for topological spaces

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, higher-category-theory

Let $(A, \{m_k\}_{k \geq 1} )$ be an $A_{\infty}$ algebra over a field $k$. Recall that this is the data of a $\mathbb{Z}$-graded $k$-vector space, along with a collection of $k$-nary operations which satisfy "homotopy associativity" relations.

Let $\overline{BA}:= \bigoplus_{\ell \geq 1} A[1]$ be the (reduced) bar complex, where $A[1]_j:= A_{j+1}$.  Let $\hat{m}_k: \overline{BA} \to A[1]$ be defined by setting for $n \geq k$ $$\hat{m}_k(x_1\otimes\dots \otimes x_n)= \sum (-1)^{|x_1|+\dots+|x_i|} x_1\otimes\dots\otimes x_i \otimes m_k(x_{i+1}\otimes\dots\otimes x_{i+k}) \otimes x_{i+k+1} \otimes \dots \otimes x_n)$$
and $\hat{m}_k=0$ otherwise.

Let $\hat{m}:= \sum_1^{\infty} \hat{m}_k$. Then one can show the following:

**Proposition**: that $\hat{m}$ is a co-derivation. In fact, there is a bijection between co-derivations on $\overline{BA}$ and $A_{\infty}$ structures on $A$.

**Question:** Suppose that my $A_{\infty}$ algebra is $C_*(\Omega X)$ for some topological space $X$. Then what is $\overline{BC_*(\Omega X)}$ and what is $\hat{m}$?  A guess would be that $\overline{BC_*(\Omega X)}$ is (reduced) chains on $X$, with the co-product given by the Alexander-Whitney map.  What is then $\hat{m}$ in this context?

Comment: My guess would rather be that the complex $(\overline{BA}, \hat{m})$ is quasi-isomorphic to $C_*(X)$, no? The map $\hat{m}$ is the differential.

Comment: Ah, I guess that makes sense. Thanks!